# Audio Code (very simple code) does not work for me

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<audio id="myAudio" src="Avengers.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('myAudio').play()
}
</script>
```

Currently testing on NotePad, worked for my friend within a game, I copied just the audio code out, did not work for me..I have the mp3 file on my file, aswell as uploaded on github. Heres the link just in case.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JosephShin7/game-dev-2018-Joseph/master/avengers-theme.mp3

--edit I already tried with the .mp3 and on my folder I renamed it to "Avengers"--

I wouldn't have posted for such a small mistake like that..I hope..

Comment: `src="Avengers"` should be `src="Avengers.mp3"`?

Comment: Or `src="avengers-theme.mp3"`?

Comment: Tried already :( I tried using the link and I forgot to put back .mp3 while asking this

Comment: @j08691 just replying..sorry wont allow me to ask another question..

Answer (score 1):

```
<audio id="myAudio" src="Avengers.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('myAudio').play()
}
</script>
```

You have to add the file's extension in the source.

Comment: Oh yeah I was messing with the code and I tried with the extensions already which did not work:( thank you for reply though. :)